# Gitlab CI Pipeline SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpunit, gitlab-ci

All migrations ran successfully. But when executing phpunit I am getting error "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')".

I even tried replacing DB_HOST=mysql with DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 and localhost. Migrations didn't run successfully and faced an errro "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = my_db and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')"

I am working around with this for 2 days. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
  DB_HOST: mysql
  DB_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
  DB_USERNAME: $MYSQL_USER
  DB_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD

cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/
    - .env

image: lorisleiva/laravel-docker:latest

composer:
  stage: build
  script:
    - composer update --prefer-dist --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts
    - cp .env.example .env
    - php artisan key:generate
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - vendor/
      - .env
    expire_in: 2 days
    when: always
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-composer
    paths:
      - vendor/

phpunit:
  stage: test
  services:
    - mysql:5.7
  dependencies:
    - composer
  script:
    - composer dump-autoload
    - php artisan config:clear
    - php artisan migrate
    - php ./vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite=Feature
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./storage/logs # for debugging
    expire_in: 1 days
    when: on_failure
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, this thing solved the issue (added `cp .env .env.testing` to the scripts in phpunit stage).
Also updated these

1. `'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock')` in
   database.php.
2. DB_PORT: 3306 in variables

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - build
  - codequality
  - test

variables:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
  DB_HOST: mysql
  DB_DATABASE: $MYSQL_DATABASE
  DB_USERNAME: $MYSQL_USER
  DB_PASSWORD: $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
  DB_PORT: 3306

cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/
    - .env

image: lorisleiva/laravel-docker:latest

composer:
  stage: build
  script:
    - composer update --prefer-dist --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts
    - cp .env.example .env
    - php artisan key:generate
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - vendor/
      - .env
    expire_in: 2 days
    when: always
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}-composer
    paths:
      - vendor/
psalm:
  stage: codequality
  dependencies:
    - composer
  script:
    - ./vendor/bin/psalm
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./storage/logs
    expire_in: 1 days
    when: on_failure

codestyle:
  stage: codequality
  dependencies: []
  script:
    - phpcs --standard=PSR2 --extensions=php app

phpunit:
  stage: test
  services:
    - mysql:5.7
  dependencies:
    - composer
  script:
    - cp .env .env.testing
    - php artisan config:clear
    - php artisan migrate
    - php ./vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite=Feature
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./storage/logs # for debugging
    expire_in: 1 days
    when: on_failure
```

Answer (score 0):

Use these changes in your `.env` files:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
```

Then in `Database.php` add folder location:

```
'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'),
```

Finally, try:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan migrate:install
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I've tried this. As I mentioned If I change DB_HOST=localhost or 127.0.0.1, I am getting connection refused, and if DB_HOST=mysql, migrations are getting created but when executing PHPUnit, getting error as "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')". And I am using Linux (not mac for unix_socket). I tried with unix_socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock but getting connection refused without creating migrations.

Comment: I have edited the answer, you can see it now.